# How to configure spring boot to talk to Redis via lettuce using username and password?

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis

I need some help to connect my spring boot application to Redis.
I have a readonly user with username and password configured in redis. Now i need to connect to redis to fetch some records using this readonly user.
I am using the Lettuce to connect to redis from spring boot but it is allowing only password. I am not finding any option to provide username.
How can i connect to redis using username and password?

Answer (score -1):

Redis has no user name but only password.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).